# How to change programatically height of Anchor Pane on demand?

Tags: java, javafx

I have vertical `SplitPane` and want to change size of inner `AnchorPane`s programatically by clicking on the button. So far, I have

```
@FXML
private void handleToggleBottomAction(ActionEvent event) {
    event.getEventType().getName();
    if(bottomToggledUp){
        bottomToggledUp = false;
        //hide bottom pane

        apBottomPane.setPrefHeight(15);
        apMapPane.setPrefHeight(750);
        apBottomPane.requestLayout();
    } else {
        // view bottom pane
        bottomToggledUp=true;
        apBottomPane.setPrefHeight(100);
        apMapPane.setPrefHeight(650);
        apBottomPane.requestLayout();
    }
}
```

But this doesn't change them? How to solve this?

Comment: Can you add the code or fxml for your layout ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `AnchorPane.setMinSize(double,double);`

now they will be force to comply